# What do you have for breakfast during camping

Tags: camping

What are some camping breakfast options if I do not wish to carry eggs? (They break)

Comment: If you get hard plastic egg containers, that should prevent your eggs from breaking. They are actually designed for camping.

Comment: Break them before you leave, take them in a bottle, and scramble them?

Comment: Kaushik, Seasoned Advice is meant for questions that can be objectively answered. "Breakfast during camping" does not meet this requirement -- the list is potentially endless. Please review our [FAQ].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oatmeal. Before you leave, mix the oats with whatever you like: brown sugar, spices, a little salt, nuts, dried fruit, even powdered milk. Boil water and mix it in your bowl so that's all you have to wash; you can boil extra water and get tea or coffee at the same time. (Other fast-cooking hot cereals would work too - I know of instant grits and instant cream of wheat, though I can't vouch for quality.)

I'm not sure if you're trying to avoid ice chests too, but there's always yogurt, or milk and cereal (something more solid like granola). And of course, fresh fruit is also always good with any meal.

For hot meals, I think baka's suggestion of premade pancake mix is probably the next best. If you're a more do-it-yourself type, you can make the mix yourself (using powdered eggs and powdered milk), but storebought will probably serve you quite well - and again, you can premix with extra ingredients like nuts, or spices for gingerbread pancakes, if you want something more exciting.

Comment: I think camping is the only excuse for the existence of instant oatmeal.

Comment: @Marti nope, still no excuse for instant oatmeal -- still really easy to make regular oatmeal since all you need to do is boil it.

Comment: Although if you do go the dark path of instant, a backpacking enthusiast friend of mine discovered that those little individual packets of instant oatmeal are lined, and you can put the hot water right in there sans bowl! (NB: i don't know what brand he had; we're in US, so probably Quaker or something along those lines? But worth investigation!)

Comment: @TJ Ellis -- the reason for instant oatmeal is to make no-bake cookies, of course!

Answer (score 2):

Since most of the time, I carry a cooler (drive-up camping), my options are a little more open.

- Hash browns (Potatoes for dinner, left overs into hash browns)
- Bacon
- French toast (I guess you could make the egg/milk mixture before hand if you don't want to carry eggs.
- Sausages
- Oatmeal (Packs small, just add water!)
- Fruit
- Toast
- Pancakes? (You could probably make the batter for this ahead of time too)

Though to be honest, generally we do take eggs and just make sure to pack them well.

Answer (score 1):

just-add-water pancake mix worked well for us.   especially when the blueberries and blackberries were in season.